# Position element in the vertical centre of the screen in a React application

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a ReactJS application, and I'm really struggling to get a component to appear in the centre of the screen.

My render method looks like this:

```
 render () {
    return (           
        <div>
          <MyComponent />

        </div>
    );
  }
```

I've seen a number of questions on here, and blog posts, that relate to this, but for one reason or another, none of them are working for me.

The most common suggestion that I've seen is to do this kind of thing:

```
<div style={{
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center"          
}}>
    <MyComponent />
</div>
```

Along with setting the height to 100%. Firstly, doing this seems to cut the control in half horizontally (that is, it squahses the contents and even cuts off one of the child controls on the far right).  Further, it doesn't position the control in the vertical centre.

Clearly I'm missing something on the CSS properties here - can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

It may be worth mentioning that, although I'm using React, I'm using it with Asp.Net Core.

EDIT

The component code is here:

```
function MyComponent(props) {

    return (        
        <div className="form-group row">

            <label htmlFor="myData" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Enter Data</label>
            <div className="col-sm-8">
                <input id="myData" className="form-control" type='text' />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-2">
                <ButtonComponent />            
            </div>
        </div>        
    );
}
export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Does it need to be in the document flow or can it be positioned using `position: absolute`?

Comment: It needs to be in the document flow, but when I've tried absolute (in desperation), I get the component squashed in the middle again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wrapper must take the whole height of the screen, which is not hapening right now. In case you are alright referencing to the the view port, you can use the following:

```
<div style={{
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center",
  height: '100vh'          
}}>
    <MyComponent />
</div>
```

Depending on your application, you could also achieve it using a relative wrapper and setting your element as absolute,

Comment: Whilst that does work (thanks!) It still squashes the control in the middle, and cuts off the far right hand control

Comment: Do you mind, sharing the code? The problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: can you check this fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/votolentino/1uLcda3o/

Comment: If you add Bootstrap, it replicates the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/zd4r5L0p/.  And if you remove the style, you can see how the style squashes the control: https://jsfiddle.net/zd4r5L0p/1/

Comment: I added width: '100%' to your `MyComponent`. It looks fine to me. I also added display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' to center the elements for a bigger view port

Comment: Glad it helped you.